# Как выбрать с помощью WHERE IN строки, где значение больше или равно?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть рабочий запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `groupid` IN (SELECT groupid FROM grouplists WHERE `usid` = '$usid')
AND reposts IN (SELECT reposts FROM grouplists WHERE `usid` = '$usid')
```

Оно выбирает те строки, где `reposts` равно именно выбранному значению, а мне нужно что бы оно выбирало строки со значением большим или равным выбранному. Как это сделать?

[image: Таблица grouplists]
[image: таблица posts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без видимой структуры сложно, но кажется, вы можете сделать без подзапросов...

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN grouplists g ON p.groupid=g.groupid
WHERE g.usid = '$usid' AND p.reposts>=g.reposts
```

Comment: Что-то у меня `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` = '1' AND p.reposts>=g.reposts` LIMIT 0, 50' at line 4`. Я обновил вопрос. Наведите на картинки - там написаны названия таблиц.

Comment: лишний апостроф был. Обновил. Проверьте мой запрос еще раз

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно исправить запрос примерно вот так.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`WHERE `groupid` IN (SELECT groupid FROM grouplists WHERE `usid` = '$usid') AND reposts IN (SELECT reposts FROM grouplists WHERE `usid` >= '$usid')
```

Либо использовать JOIN. Можете предоставить структуру таблиц, чтобы примерно понять, как их объединить?

Comment: Нет, `WHERE usid = '$usid'` это не то. Мне нужно что бы вот здесь -  `reposts IN (...)` выбиралось значение большее, или равное полученному значению в скобках.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: reposts IN  - входят в данное значение. Вам надо поставить >= вместо IN